# jQuery Mulitple input fields to limit number range and calculate to 100%

Tags: jquery

I have 9 input fields in a form which i want to ideally do the following with:

1. Each input can have a numeric value between 0 and 100
2. If for example i have 30 in 1 input, 30 in another and 40 in another it adds up to 100 (%) and disables any other fields as this the max and of course if changed it will enable the other empty fields so can add a value so until again its at 100%
3. Show in real time the total % by adding the inputted values together which will then enable the button to be click

Im not sure really where to start with this as new to this so would be really cool if someone would help on this.

This is as far as i got, it needs to have something add to look for change to change the total value, i know its not a lot but best ive got to so far:

```
    $(".control-group input").change(function() {
    var fields = $(".control-group input");
    $(fields).each(function() {
        var num = parseInt(this.value, 10);
        if (!isNaN(num)) {
            total += num;
        }
        if (total == 100){
        // disable buttons
            console.log('max reached');
        } else {
            console.log('max not reached');
        }

        $("#total").text(String(total) + '%');

    });
});
```

Above is the latest i have done, however it is not adding the % up correctly, any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without making your whole work. Please try before and ask only precise questions on the specific tasks you can't achieve.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add it in, let me get it cleaned up and updated give me 5 minutes

Comment: Probably want to start with something like [what's asked in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034672).

Comment: Ive added the code i got to so far, but stuck with the input limits on change etc..

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well? And a jsFiddle would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfZgN/) is a jsFiddle I made. It is almost at what I think you want.

JS:

```
$('input').keyup( function () {
    //limit the value to between 0 and 100
    var thisVal = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (!isNaN(thisVal)) {
        thisVal = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, thisVal));
        $(this).val(thisVal);
    }

    //get total of values
    var total = 0; 
    $('input').each(function() {
        var thisVal = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        if (!isNaN(thisVal))
            total += thisVal;
    });

    //enable submit button
    if (total == 100)
        $('#submit_button').removeAttr('disabled');
    else
        $('#submit_button').attr('disabled','disabled');        

    //update percentage
    $('#percent').html(total);
});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="control-group">
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
    <input id='submit_button' type="button" value="Submit" disabled></input>
</form>
<span id="percent">0</span>%
```

Comment: That's great, is it possible to disable the empty fields once its at 100% as it allows you to enter more and then the percent goes above 100% - thanks in advance!